# Hwo can I convert from entity to dto with Null value in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Here is my Service class.

```
public AnswerDetailResponse addAnswerByQuestionId(Long id, WriteAnswerRequest request) {

    Post post = request.toEntity();
    post.createAnswer(id);
    
    questionRepository.save(post);

    return AnswerDetailResponse.fromEntity(post);
}
```

and this is my fromEntity method of WriteAnswerRequest class

```
@ApiModel
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AnswerDetailResponse {

    private long questionId;
    private long answerId;
    private String body;
    private int score;
    ...
}

public static AnswerDetailResponse fromEntity(Post entity) {
    AnswerDetailResponse response = new AnswerDetailResponse();

    response.setQuestionId(entity.getParentId());
    response.setAnswerId(entity.getId());
    response.setBody(entity.getBody());
    response.setScore(entity.getScore());
    response.setTags(entity.getTags());
    response.setAccepted(BaseUtil.isEqual(entity.getAcceptAnswerId(), entity.getId()));
    response.setLink(SysConfig.QUESTION_DEFAULT_URL + entity.getParentId());
    response.setCreatedAt(entity.getCreatedAt());
    response.setLastEditedAt(entity.getLastEditedAt());
    response.setUsed(entity.getIsUsed());
    response.setDeleted(entity.getIsDeleted());

    return response;
}
```

now, I don't get the 'score' value from request. So, I got the Exception.
Without any library like mapstruct, modelmapper ... Is there any effective way to solve this problem..?

the Score can be got from request or not...

Comment: I assume you have `@NotNull` in your entity for score. If that is the case then simple remove this annotation to match your business scenario

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  but it's not ture. there is no @NotNull in my score... I edit the source.

Comment: `So, I got the Exception` . What is the error then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look in your Dto `AnswerDetailResponse`

```
private int score;
```

`int` is a primitive which can not hold `null` value.

Change this into

```
private Integer score;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually It could be. but In this case, Do i make all request/respons value to Wrapper class..? not primitive?

Comment: @Aloha, yes you should make the wrapper class also as Integer. Otherwise when you receive a null and you have int it will be converted to 0 value instead of null. Please don't forget to accept and upvote answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks. It is really helpful to me. and I if I got the 15 reputation, i'll upvote ur answer.
and can I ask u one more..? Either Using Wrapper class or Using Optional, which is better..?

Comment: `Optional` are the new way to move forward, but should be used wisely when needed in order to avoid spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a possibility for this line `entity.getScore()` to produce `Null`, then to set the value of score regardless, what you can do is this:

`response.setScore(Optional.ofNullable(entity.getScore()).orElse(0));`

NB: Assume the data type for `score` is an integer for example

Comment: Thanks. It could be helpful to me. is there any other way to handle it? it is also nice but I hope to be simple... like annotation someth like that... but It stil best answer to me.

Comment: Which is better code between urs(using Optional) and Panagotis(using Wrapper instead of primitive type)? how do u think?